# TCP server only send data to 1 client instead of all C#

Tags: c#, client, tcpclient, tcplistener

So I have created 2 desktop environment, one is remote and one is local.

I tried to make it so that the tcp listener send the informations to all connected client instead of just one. So what is the proper way so that the tcp listener will send the data to all connected client?

Where tcp server send message:

```
byte[] sendmsg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("check");
            streamer.Write(sendmsg, 0, sendmsg.Length);
            byte[] sendmsgs = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
            streamer.Write(sendmsgs, 0, sendmsgs.Length);
```

Where tcp client receives message:

```
else if (checkfirststr == "check")
            {
                int txtbox = streamer.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string txt = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, txtbox);
                MessageBox.Show(txt, "Data From Server");

            }
```

Code where it accept the client:

```
   while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                client = network.AcceptTcpClient();
                streamer = client.GetStream();
                worker.ReportProgress(0,"Client Accepted");
                buffers = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Client Connection Error");
                client.Close();
                streamer.Close();
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code, specifically what you have in the `Accept` portion. Accept creates a new connection for each connected client, and you need to store and manage those connections and send to all of them individually. If you want to do multicast without connection management, you should be using UDP.

Comment: Thanks so how do I make it so that it will make the data send to each client? (It my first time coding using TCP so I don't know much about it)

Comment: You haven't shown how you manage the incoming connections, so I can't tell you how to send to all of them. Basically you need to loop through all the connections and write the data to the outgoing stream.

Comment: oops sorry ok i edit the question with how i accept the connection